# LInk github repo with package on Pypi

Tags: python, github, package, pypi

I uploaded a python package on `Pypi`, but I'd also like to upload it to `Github`, so it can be opensource and anyone can contribute.

Is is possible to link the github repo with the already uploaded package on Pypi, so whenever I push something to the master branch, it also updates on Pypi?

Comment: There is, you could add a run block in your github actions workflow file.  Check out the Github documentation on `github actions`.

Comment: All suggested solutions describe how you can update a PyPi package based on the code in the remote GitHub repository, i.e. with a workflow and a corresponding yml file (if I understand correctly).

What I am doing (and what I think the question refers to) is updating PyPi manually from a local repository with build and twine. Is there an option to retrospectively show this (versions and latest release etc.) on GitHub as well? 

I ran into the issue that one time I updated PyPi from GitHub and now the manual update is incompatible with that version.. wouldn't suggest mixing the two ways...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your Github repository there is a tab called Actions (next to Pull requests) where there are several actions like "Publish Python Package".

[image: Python Package Action]

Selecting it will automatically add the relevant Code to your repository. You then only need to store your credentials, like username & password.
You can do so under Settings > Secrets > Actions

[image: Add repository secrets]

Comment: What if I do the publishing to PyPI manually myself? How can I tell GitHub in that case that there actually is a linked package on PyPI?

Answer (score 1):

Go to PyPI -> Your Repo -> Manage -> Publishing -> Add your GitHub Details.